# How to get contacts of personal Microsoft accounts using Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, msal.js

I have implemented MSAL library by using Azure AD dashboard, granted permissions for user.read, user.read.all, contacts.read, contacts.read.all, openid, profile, directory.read.all. Tenants(the accounts on the same organization) are able to sign in their accounts and able to get their contacts using access token. When I try any microsoft personal account, signing in works well, able to get access token but when I make Microsoft Graph api call using endpoint(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts) I am getting 401 Unauthorized error.

When I check the response object of the request to get access token, for tenants, the response includes the scopes array as:

```
scopes: Array(13)
0: "Calendars.Read"
1: "Calendars.Read.Shared"
2: "Calendars.ReadWrite"
3: "Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared"
4: "Contacts.Read"
5: "Directory.AccessAsUser.All"
6: "Directory.Read.All"
7: "openid"
8: "profile"
9: "User.Read"
10: "User.Read.All"
11: "User.ReadBasic.All"
12: "email"
```

and

for personal accounts, it is:

```
scopes: Array(2)
0: "openid"
1: "profile"
```

Somehow, personal accounts are not getting permissions for the scopes that are granted by admin.

Also supported account type for my registered app is:

```
Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox, Outlook.com)
All users with a work or school, or personal Microsoft account can use your application or API. This includes Office 365 subscribers.
```

Here is the configuration in my code to sign in the user:

```
let msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: <client_id>
};
let signinScopes = ['user.read.all', 'contacts.read'];
```

and scopes I pass when I make access token request:

```
let tokenRequest = {
          scopes: ["user.read.all"]
        };
```

When I pass token below, it gives the error 'The request was denied because one or more scopes requested are unauthorized or expired. The user must first sign in and grant the client application access to the requested scope.'

```
 var tokenRequest = {
          scopes: ["user.read.all", "contacts.read"]
        };
```

I am expecting to get contacts of all signed in Microsoft Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot request `user.read.all` for Microsoft (aka Personal) Accounts.

The scope request should look like this:

```
scopes: ["user.read", "contacts.read"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Changed it, still gives the same error.

Comment: Were you presented with the consent dialog?

Comment: No, on the consent dialog, it only says to 'view your basic profile' for personal account as well